# How to set parent window overtop child window in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want the parent window to always be on top of the child window.

```
QMainWindow a();
a.show();

QMainWindow b(&a);
mat.show();
```

How to set `a` over `b`?

Comment: With such setup you will probably have only one window, where `b` is inside of `a`. For having two windows you don't have to set such a relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup seems a bit weird. The mainwindow B with A as its parent. If you want to have independants window, I think you should remove the inheritance link.

In this cas, you can change the order of the show calls to change the order of the window :

```
QMainWindow a;
QMainWindow b;

b.show();
a.show();
```

If you're sure that's the way you want to go, you have mlultiple solution.

May you can call the show method in an other order ? Untested.

Maybe you can set up the windows flags before calling the show. If you want to have A over everything, in a permanent way, you change the windows flags :

It would be something like:

```
QMainWindow a;
QMainWindow b;

a.setWindowsFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint| Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint);
a.show();
b.show();
```

If you want to manipulate the "who is over who" in your app, maybe you should unite them in a stack, or giving them a common ancestor, or something like that.